# C issue: int value in struct is weird when using assignment via pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-search-tree, function-definition

I'm quite new in C and wanted to write code for a Binary-Tree with methods for inserting, deleting and wahtever.
In the code, I use value = 0 in order to show that the struct is undefined yet. (I don't know any better way). Problem: We shouldn't insert the value 0.
The main problem I have: Why does `printf("%d\n", root.pLeft->value);` print the number 6422476 instead of 3??
Here is the whole code:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *pLeft;
    struct Node *pRight;
};

void insert(struct Node *root, int value) {
    struct Node *current = root;
    while (current->value != 0) {
        if (value < current->value) {
            current = current->pLeft;
        } else {
            current = current->pRight;
        }
    }
    current->value = value;
    struct Node newLeft;
    newLeft.value = 0;
    struct Node newRight;
    newRight.value = 0;
    current->pLeft = &newLeft;
    current->pRight = &newRight;
}

int main() {
    struct Node root;
    root.value = 0;

    insert(&root, 4);
    insert(&root, 3);

    printf("%d\n", root.value);
    printf("%d\n", root.pLeft->value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

`

---

Comment: what happens to the variables newLeft and newRight after the function "insert" returns?

Comment: The addresses are stored and remain in the node (pLeft and pRight) that contains the new inserted value. Or not?
When inserting another value, insert will go through the nodes and set the new value into the node that was newLeft or newRight previously.

Comment: I didn't ask about the addresses. What happens to the *variables* in a function when the function returns?

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean. They get destroyed and and do not exist anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```cpp
    struct Node newLeft;
    newLeft.value = 0;
    struct Node newRight;
    newRight.value = 0;
    current->pLeft = &newLeft;
    current->pRight = &newRight;
}
```

`newLeft` and `newRight` are local varialbes in storage class "auto", thus they will die (end their lifetime) at the end of the enclosing block.

But you are using (the addresses to) these objects *outside the block* because their address escape the block.  So you have dangling pointers.

Solution is to dynamically allocate the objects by meand of `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Within the function `insert` data members `pLeft` and `pRight` are set to addresses of local objects with automatic storage duration.

```
current->value = value;
struct Node newLeft;
newLeft.value = 0;
struct Node newRight;
newRight.value = 0;
current->pLeft = &newLeft;
current->pRight = &newRight;
```

These objects `newLeft` and `newRight` will not be alive after exiting the function. So the pointers `pLeft` and `pRight` will be invalid and dereferencing them will invoke undefined behavior.

Your approach is wrong. You need to use pointers of the type `struct Node *` that will point to dynamically allocated nodes in the tree. Start from this declaration in `main`

```
struct Node *root = NULL;
```

and then the function `insert` will dynamically allocate nodes of the tree if it is required.

The function can be defined for example the following way

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *pLeft;
    struct Node *pRight;
};

int insert( struct Node **root, int value ) 
{
    while ( *root != NULL ) 
    {
        if ( value < ( *root )->value ) 
        {
            root = &( *root )->pLeft;
        } 
        else 
        {
            root = &( *root )->pRight;
        }
    }

    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value  = value;
        new_node->pLeft  = NULL;
        new_node->pRight = NULL;

        *root = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called like

```
struct Node *root = NULL;

insert( &root, 4 );
insert( &root, 3 );

printf( "%d\n", root->value );
printf( "%d\n", root->pLeft->value );
```